# Is it quicker to use string.Format or interpolation with $"..."?

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

Of these two methods of string interpolation (string.Format and the "$" operator), is one better than the other and if so, in what situations and why?

Examples of both doing the same thing:

```
//string.Format
string s = string.Format("( {0} ) , ( {1} )", string.Join(", ", columnNames),string.Join(", ",values));

//"$" interpolation operator
string s = $"( {string.Join(", ", columnNames)} ) , ( {string.Join(", ", values)} )";
```

Comment: Have you benchmarked them?

Comment: Stack Overflow users are kind of biased against premature optimization, and rightfully so. In general, stuff like this really doesn't matter unless you want to execute it hundreds of thousands of times, while your code is not doing anything else. As soon as disk or network access comes into play, the relatively tiny performance differences, if any, won't matter at all in the bigger picture. See also the classical ["If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then **race your horses**."](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: You should check out what StackOverflow's own Nick Craver [was tweeting about last night](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/702691498383511552) (link to first of a few tweets discussing this).

Comment: Am I the only one who initially read the title to mean "is it quicker to *write code* using string.Format or interpolation?" and thinking to myself "is this a trick question?"

Answer (score 2):

String interpolation is turned into `string.Format()` at compile-time so they should end up with the same result. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342392/string-interpolation-vs-string-format))

Answer (score 0):

Benchmark has been done, please [check this out](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-interpolation)

Globally, it is similar to string.Format, but variables may be accessed directly (not through index arguments) so you won't notice any major difference.

But if you are looking for performance, the length of the strings to be concatenate will make the choice between the different concatenantion methods very difficult.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't answers. Include the relevant details from the link into your answer.