# How do I create a string dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, string-formatting

I am developing an application for **managing Personal Hotspot of a Laptop**
 (Windows of Course).
I'm having a little difficulty in **changing the Hotspot Name**.
Here is my Code:

```
//For CMD Command
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new 
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

//Reading User Input in textBox1:
string name = textBox1.Text;

//CMD Argument:..., Which is currently written wrong to make it Easy to 
//understand the problem

startInfo.Arguments = "/C netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid="name";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Here, In the `Arguments` line, the syntax is wrong. The value assigned to `Arguments` should be a single string. I need to incorporate `name`, that has a dynamic value, with the rest of the string that is constant. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something here, seems to me that a simple string concatenation would do it:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/C netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid=" + name;
```

Comment: but then again, I only had 2 hours of sleep, so it's totally possible I'm missing something...

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can create a dynamic string:

For your specific case, [Concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341188/string-concatenation-using-operator) is the best choice as your `string` is very simple.The reason you would choose this method for your case is because it is very light as compared to other methods and has a clean enough syntax.

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/C netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid=" + name;
```

For anything more complicated, `string.Format` is a popular go to. You would generally use it to combine more complex `strings` than your example. [This tutorial](https://www.dotnetperls.com/format) covers the subject thoroughly.

```
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/C netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid={0}", name);
```

The release of `C#6.0` included a neat feature: [interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings). It is for the most part just [syntactic sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32342460/7159784) for `string.Format`, where the line below is turned into the line above at compile time. There are subtle differences, but those are not important in this thread.

```
startInfo.Arguments = $"/C netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid={name}";
```

And lastly, if you need to change a string more than a few times (I usually use the rule of 5 - i.e. a string changes more than 5 times), I would use the `StringBuilder` class. A great application, among many others, would be a long loop that modifies a certain string each iteration. [See This Tutorial](https://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder). 
In this case, the Garbage Collector will thank you for a using a `StringBuilder`!

Comment: String interpolation is even more readable: `startInfo.Arguments = $"/C netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid={name}";`

Comment: Format and interpolated strings are better for code readability, but concatenation is the best option in terms of performance when combining a small number of strings, string builder is better when you have a lot of strings.